# Split a string, two words at a time

Tags: java, split

I have

```
String input = "one two three four five six seven";
```

Is there a regex that works with `String.split()` to grab (up to) two words at a time, such that:

```
String[] pairs = input.split("some regex");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pairs));
```

results in this:

```
[one two,two three, three four,four five,five six,six seven]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
String[] elements = input.split(" ");
List<String> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < elements.length - 1; i++) {
    pairs.add(elements[i] + " " + elements[i + 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No. With String.split(), the things you get out can't overlap.

e.g. you can get: `"one two three four"` -> `{"one","two","three","four"}`, but not `{"one two","two three", "three four"}`

Comment: But JB Nizet's answer will certainly solve your problem